# Rele, relay, relevador no enciende al ejecutar shell_exec o exec de python en php7

Tags: python, python-3.x, php7, raspberry-pi

Hola tengo este código en la Raspberry pi zero w:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
<?php
/**
 * Ejecutando el encendido
 * 
 * Se ejecuta el encendidom apagado y encendido programado.
 */

if (isset($_POST["1sec"]))
    {
        exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/relay.py");
        $que_hay = "Hola que hay, si se envió, pero ejecuta?";
        echo $que_hay;

        function success() {
            $mystring = exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/relay.py', $output);
            var_dump($output);

        }
        success();
    }

?>

<h1>Encender la puerta</h1>

<p>A conntinuación tenermos estas opciones para prender y apagar el Relé.</p>

<form action="index.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <button name="1sec">Prender 1 segundo</button>
    <button type="submit" value="">Encender</button>
    <button type="submit" value="">Apagar</button>

</form>
<a href="execute.php">test</a>
<a href="test2.php">test2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

y tengo mi archivo relay.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

El cual funciona en terminal con `$python relay.py`

No encuentro el problema al ejecutar con php dicha, ya he probado con discreciones relativas, shell_exec(), exec(), y el archivo php.ini no tiene esa función en desactivado

```
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
```

No se que mas hacer...

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi     210 oct 14 22:51 execute.php

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10701 oct 14 17:29 index.html_

-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi    1131 oct 14 23:29 index.php

-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi     210 oct 14 23:39 relay.py

-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi     655 oct 14 21:32 test2.php

Esta esto.

Comment: Me faltó agregar a "/etc/sudoers" -->   www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL Y funciona. Muchas gracias de todos modos @Trauma

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    /**
     * Ejecutando el encendido
     * 
     * Se ejecuta el encendidom apagado y encendido programado.
     */

    if (isset($_POST["1sec"]))
        {
            exec("sudo python relay.py");
            $que_hay = "Hola que hay, si se envió, pero ejecuta?";
            echo $que_hay;
            /*
            function success() {
                $mystring = exec('sudo /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/relay.py', $output);
                var_dump($output);
            }
            success();*/
        }

    ?>

    <h1>Encender la puerta</h1>
    <p>Hola Guillermo y Mauricio</p>
    <p>A conntinuación tenermos estas opciones para prender y apagar el Relé.</p>

    <form action="index.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <button name="1sec">Prender 1 segundo</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Con el archivo relay.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

ir a $sudo vim /etc/sudoers y agregar al final.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Después

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Volver a cargar la pagina y el relé funciona perfectamennte